# Outlook adding space in HTML email

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I know this is a common problem, I've searched high and low for a solution.  Everything I've come across, I've tried.  If I had any hair left I would be pulling it out.

I have a table that has a series of bullet points.  The problem with this table is that whenever I create a new row, Outlook decides to add extra spacing below each row, making my table look larger than it should be.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ExternalClass table, .ExternalClass tr, .ExternalClass td {line-height: 100%;}
</style>

<table width="400" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <td width="10" align="right" valign="top" style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      &bull;
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="380" align="left" valign="top" style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      Info next to bullet
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <td width="10" align="right" valign="top" style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      &bull;
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width="380" align="left" valign="top" style="border:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
      Info next to bullet
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Things I've tried that did not work:

`border-collapse:collapse`

`display:block`

`display:inline-block`

`float:left`

Comment: Have you tried without the `<p>` tags? When you say it's inserting space below the row, do you mean inbetween each `<tr>` ?

Comment: It works! I turned the `<p>` tags into `<span>` and everything looks perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: Good stuff :) I've added that as an answer, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `<p>` tags, mail clients don't always respect styling on those and they'll automatically add an extra line break afterwards.

You can replace the `<p>` with a `<span>` if needs be, as `<span>` doesn't come with any 'free' padding.

Comment: It's safer to switch to `<span>` so I can keep my in-line styling since some email clients don't always read styling in `<td>`, but yes, this worked.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include that, just in case please don't read the comments :)

Comment: What client's ignore inline styles on `<td>`s? I have never encountered this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook.com adds embedded CSS that overrides line heights, and both Outlook and Outlook.com don't support`<p>` margins very well, if at all: I found the `<p>` tag tip in an online forum (Campaign Monitor I think), but I could never get it to work consistently:

*HTML/Inline CSS:*

```
<p style="margin-bottom:0;margin:0 0 1em;padding:0;">some text here</p>
```

**Do This to Fix The Issue**

To override Outlook.com line-height, do the following:

*Embedded CSS:*

```
.ExternalClass * { line-height:105%; }
```

For consistent padding/margins across all email clients/user agents, I use `<span>` tags and padding (no margin attributes) to the `<td>` container:

*HTML/Inline CSS*

```
<td class="classname" style="padding-bottom: 3px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 15px;">
  Text Goes Here
</td>
```

Note: I add a class name to style for responsive design where supported.

Note: I found `mso-line-height-rule: exactly` for Outlook 2003/2007/2010/2013. It only works if used on a block-level element, and it must be listed as the first attribute before line-height (like in the example above).

**General Tips:**

- Add all inline styles to block-level tags if possible.
- Put headings and the related content that follows in separate table rows so I can add padding to the containing `<td>` of the heading. It may be a little excessive, but it gives you more control on spacing than anything else I've found.

*HTML/Inline CSS:*

```
<tr>
  <td class="introHead" style="padding-bottom:3px;color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;">
    Heading goes here
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="introCopy" style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;">
    This is the body of the text, Lorem Ipsum yadda yadda.
  </td>
</tr>
```