# White space in outlook html newsletter

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Ok, I have this html template. It was created in photoshop and then I use slice tool to export pictures.

Now, when i send the mail, gmail and yahoo render ok but outlook... create white spaces between images (tables)

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/4240/j98x.jpg

Can you please tell me how to fix this? Only in Outlook I have this problem (big)

I use this CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">            
        #outlook a{padding:0;} 
        body{width:100% !important;} 
        body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} 

        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
        img{border:none; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none; text-transform:capitalize;}
    </style>
```

and of corse style="display:block" at every image

Comment: From what I understand, Outlook is fairly picky about it's styling. I've had luck in the past using in-line styles instead of the style sheet format. Take a look at this for a more detailed run-down: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: It's hard to say exactly how the issue looks and is occurring, but perhaps this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091956/outlook-adding-space-in-html-email

Specifically in taking out the <p> tags and swapping them for <span>

Comment: I do not have <p> tags. Actually when I export from photoshop, in that .html file I have alot of <tr><td><tr><td><tr><td>. Also I have Unsupported HTML Elements and Attributes Compared with the HTML 4.01 Specification like td colspan="2 or 12 or another number", and of corse I have td rowspan="2 or 12 or another number". If t his is the problem, what can I do

Comment: I`ve found sollution here http://www.outlook-apps.com/html-emails-photoshop/#!prettyPhoto For me, problem was from export settings in photoshop (save for web)

Answer (score 1):

Hi to Avoid white spaces in between images in newsletters,

We have to give display:block; for each image and give border:0px; for table and td,tr .

Hope it will help for you a bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

and make sure your images all have this:

```
style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Suman.
Make sure that if you are using images in your email newsletter - you accompany inline style as well with it.

Example: `<img src="image path/image.ext" style="display: block;" />`

You might want to go through this tutorial [creating html email newsletter](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/creating-html-email-newsletters-with-dreamweaver) - It can help you!