# How to get rid of extra space between HTML td and table within in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

Here is the code of the HTML email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {
                    #wrapper {
                            width: 100% !important;
                    }
            }

            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
                mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }

            a {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 22px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #ff8000;
            }

            p {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 22px;
                color: #797571;
            }

            span {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 18px;
                line-height: 18px;
                color: #383635;
            }

            small {
                color: #9f9d9d;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 18px;
            }

            img {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <table id="wrapper" align="center" width="740" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td background="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/email-bg.png" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" width="740" valign="top">
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:740px;">
                            <v:fill type="tile" src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/email-bg.png" color="#f5f5f5" />
                            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div>
                            <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="55">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="55">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="55">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="130" style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/logo-mobile.png" border="0"
                                            width="240" height="50" style="display: block" alt="Транссертико" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="60" style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                        <h1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; color: #383635; font-weight: normal;">Здравствуйте, Иван!</h1>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Мы очень рады, что Вы присоединились к числу клиентов Транссертико!
                                        Дарим Вам <a href="#">скидку 5%</a> на первый заказ, чтобы поскорее познакомиться поближе!</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="118" height="170">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                        <p>С уважением,<br>
                                        Холдинговая Компания<br>
                                        ТРАНССЕРТИКО</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="118">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background: #ededed;" height="100">
                                    <td width="118" height="170">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/indent.gif" border="0"
                                            width="1" height="1" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 0em;">
                                        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-size: 0em;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50" valign="top">
                                                    <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/email-tel.png" border="0"
                                                width="28" height="28" style="display: block" alt="Телефон"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="200">
                                                    <span>+7 495 617-61-16</span><br />
                                                    <small>Многоканальный</small>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span>8 800 700-61-17<span><br />
                                                    <small>Бесплатно по России</small>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50" valign="bottom">
                                                    <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/email-mail.png" border="0"
                                                width="28" height="28" style="display: block" alt="Телефон"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="200" height="50" colspan="2" valign="bottom">
                                                    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #9f9e9d;">E-mail: </span> <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;">dostavka@dtod.ru</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="112" valign="bottom" align="right">
                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                            <img src="http://nineseven.ru/html/transsertiko/img/email-footer-bg.png" border="0"
                                            width="112" height="128" style="display: block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            </v:textbox>
                        </v:rect>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The email looks good in every browser but it has an extra space between #container and the table at the bottom in Outlook 2007.
I tried to add

```
mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-size: 0em;
```

to that table but there was no success. I also tried to add vertical-align properties to containing tr and td. :( Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get some help from here [Outlook adding space in HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091956/outlook-adding-space-in-html-email)

Also I think you should remove the divs and put the styling on td instead. Some email clients does not like html-tags inside tables.

Comment: I need divs to support background images in Outlook