# html code doesn't give the same output in outlook email as in browser

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a small html code which gives the expected output when run through browser but when I use the same with in outlook email it doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr>
    <td style="padding-left:50;"></td>  
    <td style="display:block;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;height:150; width:500;margin:0">
    <a href=https://www.mytitlelink>
    <p style="font-size:12px;font-family:Graphik;color:blue;text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;margin:0">This is my title here</p></a>
    <p style="font-size:12px;font-family:Graphik;color:black;margin:0">
Here goes my text. Figuring a way to remove leading blank link above title and reduce the spacing between title and this text. Tried using line-spacing, margin, padding but no luck. Everything works fine when access this html text through browser but troubling me when the same is used with inthe outlook email. 
Here goes my text
Here goes my text ...<a href=https://www.mytitlelink> read more</a></p>
    <p style=" font-size:12px;font-family:Graphik;color:black;">Source:MySource<br>Published On:Date</p>
    </td>
</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Not able to get rid of Leading blank line on top of the title and line spacing between title and the text when using outlook email.

attaching screen shots
[Output from Outlook Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqjRW.png)
[Output from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtZTq.png)

Went through different links and understood html code in email behaves differently than browser but no luck in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just figured it out its `<p>` tag which is causing an issue. Found here [Outlook adding space in HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091956/outlook-adding-space-in-html-email). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

When emails are sent with HTML the service you are sending it to (be it gmail, outlook, etc.) will filter your html and then remake it with their own set of "rules". To give you a good answer we would need what parts get messed up and also what verison of outlook you are using. I suggest you take a look at [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) since it helps debug css inconsistencies with email clients.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I have attached a screenshot showing how I expected and what is messing up in outlook. Outlook version I am using is Office365 ProPlus. Thanks for the link.